# How to format data from EditText

Tags: java, android

I'm programming an app and trying to figure out how to format data from an EditText field

The data will look something like this

```
somename 123 445.46
somename2 56 234
somename3 34 42.65
```

What I want to do is move the first set of numbers to the left side

```
123 somename 445.46
56 somename2 234
34 somename3 42.65
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
public static String formatData(String str){
   String[] temp = str.split(" ");
   if(temp.length > 2){
      return temp[1]+" "+temp[0]+" "+temp[2];
   }else{
      // can't perform.
      return str;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works, I have marked it as answer. Is there a way to run this on multiple lines? I'm still somewhat new to this

Comment: @Greg432, have edited the answer. You can call this method.